# Como utilizar um Command Button inserido na Planilha no codigo VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Tenho um botão de comando que inseri em uma planilha, e queria saber qual função tenho que atribuir no codigo vba, para saber quando um usuário clicar nele !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Se for um botão de Active-x *Controles Active-X* clique duas vezes no botão e ele irá abrir no VBA uma *Sub* para criar seu código.
2. Se for um botão comum *Controles de Formulários*, você poderá criar sua macro e depois clique com o botão direito sobre o botão, selecione a opção *Atribuir macro...*, selecione sua macro e terá seu botão executando a função que deseja.

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 2):

Sobre o contador de cliques, você pode fazer com que ele some em uma célula qualquer quando o usuário clicar no botão. 
Por exemplo:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value = Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value + 1

End Sub
```

Com certeza você vai encontrar formas mais eficazes de se fazer isso, mas essa é a mais simples até onde eu sei!

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia,

Consegui resolver, utilizando o botão ActiveX, quando alguém clica nele ele atribuí uma variável que habilita uma planilha específica.

Obrigado a todos pela colaboração.